# How do I put div classes in SQL statement?

Tags: css, sql, mysqli

I am trying to organize several of my columns from my SQL database by div classes. My columns in this instance are title, start_date, and location. Here's the part of my code I'm trying to add the div classes to:

```
group_concat('<div>', title, '</div>', '<div>', start_date, '</div>', '<div>', location, '</div>' ORDER BY title DESC SEPARATOR '<br>') as data FROM events
```

With this code, my page is showing the divs around the title, for example, but I want to add distinct classes to each column so that it shows a div class but can't figure out the proper syntax on how to show this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do want to add a css class to a div tag?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, that was my bad. I want to add it within the SQL statement though. When I do <div class="title"> in the SQL statement, the page returns an error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to do it like this.
You could always easily do all these after running the basic query using php or whatever language you're using

```
SELECT * FROM events
```

If I understand it right, you need css classes inside each tag. Which should work if you just add them while you run concat

```
group_concat('<div class="class1">', title, '</div>', '<divclass="class2">', start_date, '</div>', '<div class="class3">', location, '</div>' ORDER BY title DESC SEPARATOR '<br>') as data FROM events
```

Comment: Since I'm doing a GROUP_CONCAT, I am defining the variable in php as $data = $row['data']. I wasn't sure how to define each column (title, start_date,etc.) within the "data" variable

Comment: When I try it your way, my page is returning an error

Comment: Why do you need group concat if you could just do this: 
`select title,start_date,location from event`
and in your php file just iterate through the values and add the div tags from there

Comment: I didn't include my entire statement, but I am grouping title, start_date, location through a GROUP BY, hence the GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Then you may use group concat and output csv data. Seperate the text into an array using commas using str_getcsv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

div {  padding:10px; background-color:red; color: white;  }

group_concat('', title, '', '', start_date, '', '', location, '' ORDER BY title DESC SEPARATOR '
') as data FROM events

Or

.cls {  padding:10px; background-color:red; color: white;  }

group_concat('', title, '', '', start_date, '', '', location, '' ORDER BY title DESC SEPARATOR '
') as data FROM events

Comment: I need the classes to be different for each column. So different class for title, start_date, location, etc.

Comment: Then you should define each class in your page and call it where you want it.eg class1{ color:red} , class2{ color: blue} etc